# How to add Border around widget in Blogger

Tags: css, widget, border, title, blogger

I'm looking for is the trick to create that border around the widget as shown in the image:

[image: Mockup]

And the *title* should stick to the top.

Any idea how to do that kinda trick?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I didn't know what the code is and which to edit. I've tried the code given below but it didn't work on my blog I wonder why :(

Answer (score 1):

You can  use like this -

```css
body{
  background: #ccc;
}
.border-col{
  min-height: 300px;width: 220px;
  background: #ccc;border:2px solid #fff;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  position: relative;
}
.border-col h2{
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -13px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="border-col">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Maddy, can you tell me where should I put the code? Is it on Template > Advanced > Add CSS? Because I've tried to put it there and nothing happened to the widget. I've got a dark grey background instead.